# How to call a method from an onclick button? - visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, methods, call

I am using visual studio express 2013 for Web.

I have a class named: About.cshtml and inside the class I have a button called: Reset Data which is used to reset data from the database.

The code below show the work I've done in *About.cshtml* class in order to call the method.

```
<button class="Resetbutton" onclick="resetmethod">Reset Data</button>
@{
protected void resetmethod()
{
    statsMethod reset = new statsMethod(); 
    reset.reset_button(User.Identity.GetUserName());
}
```

The code below shows the method named: reset_button in the class named: *statsmethod.cs*.

```
public void reset_button(string userID)
{
    try
    {
        var reset_results =
                    from details in db.TriviaResults
                    where details.UserId == userID
                    select details;

        var reset_answers =
                    from details in db.TriviaAnswers
                    where details.UserId == userID
                    select details;

        foreach (var detail in reset_results)
        {
            db.TriviaResults.Remove(detail); //DeleteOnSubmit(detail);
        }

        foreach (var detail in reset_answers)
        {
            db.TriviaAnswers.Remove(detail); //DeleteOnSubmit(detail);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

What I've done is to try to call 'reset_button' method where it will delete data from database.
If anyone could help me fix my problem please I would appreciate.

Please do not leave bad feedback .. if something is incorrect or you need more information just let me know, else you won't be of any help.

PS: I had to edit the previous question because I am blocked to ask any other questions.
Thanks.

Comment: We have no context here. We don't know what kind of web application you're writing, or the scope of those variables. You should also consider whether you're going to end up losing significant state if your web application is restarted for some reason..

Comment: The scope is that I am building a loop during the program.
Now I need to initialize the variables and set them to 0 at the start of the program. 
I thought there is a command to let the line be read only once.

Comment: You might want to mention that in the question then, otherwise we have very little to go on.

Comment: Are you simply looking for (hopefully private; potentially static) [Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173118.aspx)? You *can* give them an initial value, however `0` happens to be the default for `int` fields already.

Comment: I arranged the question as much as I could. 
I am looking for a solution to assign the variable to 0 once and then let the loop increment the variables without being assigned to 0 again while looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have this code which I need it to be read only once at the start of the program

The example gives field initializers on a controller. A controller instance is not synonymous with a "program"; a controller instance more commonly maps to a *single request* (although in the case of partials, it can actually be just a fragment of a request).

If you want to do something once and once only, a static field initializer may be useful; however, it is unclear what you would want to do in your scenario, as with anything *static*, the scores would be shared between **all users** - not usually what is wanted. Also: unless you understand concurrency in the context of your chosen framework (which from the question: you don't), `static` fields should usually be `readonly` and immutable.

A more appropriate solution in your case is probably per-client state; probably "session-state".

Comment: The program have a question for the user and the user answer the question. 
Now I want to hold statistics about how much correct and incorrect answers the user manage to get right or wrong. 

The only way I see it is to build a counter to holds the amount of correct and incorrect answers the user is getting. 

The method which shows if the answer is correct or not is in the controller, therefore I thought of placing the counter right after I know whether the answer is correct or not.

Comment: @Charlot which again: sounds like a scenario for session-state; or a database; not controller fields

Answer (score 0):

You can assign 0 i.e  falseAns = 0 in constructor So It will not again and again assign 0 in loop.